# Constraint Violation Exception using sequence in JPA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data in my project and using JPA for mapping between the entity and my table, 
this is my entity

```
public class daoTable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_table_nc", sequenceName = "SEQ_TABLE_NC")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_table_nc")
private Long id;
// setter && getter && outher params
}
```

and this is my Repo

```
public interface daoTable Repository extends JpaRepository<daoTable , Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<daoTable >{}
```

when I try to save I get this problem :

1. `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [GQAO.PK_RT]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`
2. `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you already have records in database with the same values as your `SequenceGenerator` will generate.

For example if I save 1 record without using this `SequenceGenerator` (`seq_table_nc`) after that add it in the code this `SequenceGenerator` (`seq_table_nc`) and try to save I will get the exception that you have because the generator can give me value that is equal to value that I already have in database.

Generally you should check which value try to save in DB for `id`. After that you have to see how to update your database `SequenceGenerator` so it start generate unique values.

Good luck!